How Barlow Twins avoid embeddings that differ by affine transformation?
I am reading the Barlow Twins (BT) paper and just don't get how it can avoid the following scenario.
The BT loss is minimized when the cross-correlation matrix equals the identity matrix. A necessary condition for this to happen is that the diagonal elements $C_{ii}$ are 1. This can be achieved in 2 different ways. For each $x$:

$z_A = z_B$
$z_A = a\cdot z_B + b$

where $z_A$ and $z_B$ are augmentations of the same input $x$.
Intuitively, if our aim is to learn representations invariant to distortions, then the 2nd solution should be avoided. Are there any ideas on what drives the network to avoid this scenario?

If the $z_A$ and $z_B$ have the same mean of $0$ and variance of $1$ then you would have $a=1$ and $b=0$.
The paper talks about this on page 3 as "batch normalization" and in the code.  On page 8 it says

In INFONCE, the embeddings are typically normalized along the feature dimension to compute a cosine similarity between embedded samples. We normalize the embeddings along the batch dimension instead.


Zero mean and unit variance can easily be achieved with standardization as you have noted. However, this doesn't guarantee that the network learns proper embeddings. If for downstream tasks we use the embeddings before normalization, then for the same input it is not guaranteed that we will get the same representation.
